# Can't seem to solve this NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

The error I'm getting is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.me.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
```

Lines 34-39 in `MainActivity.java` are as follows:

```
light_switch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        turn_torch_on();
    }
});
```

This leads me to believe that `light_switch` is returning `null`, despite this on line 31:

```
light_switch = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.light_switch);
```

I've double checked the id is correct. Is there anything that I'm missing? I'm not really sure what I can do to fix this at this moment.

The exception log is available here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=yDPRjvry

### MainActivity.java

```
package com.me.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageButton light_switch;

private boolean has_flash;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    // get the light switch
    light_switch = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.light_switch);

    // make the light switch work
    light_switch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            turn_torch_on();
        }
    });

    // check if device has flash capability
    has_flash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

    // alert user that their device is not supported
    if ( !has_flash ) {
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        alert.setTitle("Sorry :(");
        alert.setMessage("Your device does not have a flash");
        alert.show();
        return;
    }

}

/**
 * turn torch on
 */
private void turn_torch_on() {
    // change the layout to off
    toggle_layout();
}

/**
 * toggle layout for on/off
 */
private void toggle_layout() {
    light_switch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_on);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

### fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_off"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/light_switch"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/button_off"
        android:contentDescription="On/Off switch" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? Have you tried cleaning the project and building again?

Comment: check light_switch in xml

Comment: Using Android Studio. Any idea how to clean the project/rebuild in AS?

Comment: `R.id.light_switch` is in a fragment but you're trying to find it in the activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R.id.light_switch` is part of `PlaceholderFragment`'s layout *not* of your `MainActivity`'s.

Just because a Fragment is part of an Activity's layout, it does not mean that whatever Views the Fragment possesses are made public to the enclosing Activity.

Either move the button so it becomes a part of your Activity's `activity_main.xml` layout, **or** move the click handling and other logic to the `PlaceholderFragment`.

Comment: You are correct, and the first to respond so it's my duty to award you the tick. Thank you for your help. I moved everything out of the fragment, because KISS.

Answer (score 2):

You are inflating the fragment_main.xml (which contains your ImageButton) on onCreateView of PlaceholderFragment. Try this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
 // get the light switch
    light_switch = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.light_switch);

 // make the light switch work
     light_switch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        turn_torch_on();
    }
});
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: This would've been the more interesting choice. I decided to not use the fragment in the end. Still, thank you for your answer. I'll keep it on hand for the future.

Answer (score 1):

I think ImageButton's initialization  in PlaceholderFragment is the correct way.
Beside,use Android Studio or Intellij Idea to clean and build project you can choose menu Build->Rebuild Project

Comment: Now I know how to rebuild the project. Cheers!